# Где хранить файлы html в android studio?

Tags: java, android

возникла проблема, не знаю как обратиться к файлу html и куда его кидать в android studio?

Вот код:

```
static final String DEFAULT_FILE = "index.html";
File file = new File(WEB_ROOT, fileRequested);
```

Comment: можете положить в "res/raw"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный файл нужно загрузить в папку `assets/` (если ее нет то создайте). И дальше данный файл можно вызвать таким образом:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);

    myLocationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.addJavascriptInterface(new Locater(), "locater");
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/geoweb1.html");
  }
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846475/webview-does-not-work-with-local-html-files?noredirect=1&lq=1) есть подобный вопрос.

Comment: добавил в папку assets, вставил путь "file:///android_asset/index.html", но путь не находит. Мне не надо открывать его в WebView, мне надо передать этот файл, при GET запросе.

Comment: куда вы его должны передать?

Comment: я по сути делают веб сервер на android. Но при запросе на получение страницы(из-за неправильного пути) выдает, что сервер ничего не прислал. А в логах пишет, что путь к файлу не правильный.

Comment: ты знаешь как указать путь к файлу лежащий в папке assets в string? Извини, за глупые вопросы :D

Comment: замените папку с android_assets на assets или как там она у вас называется

Comment: выдает такое исключение:
Error with file not found exception : file:/asset/index.html (No such file or directory)

Comment: `file:///assets/index.html` - я думаю должен быть такой путь. Проверьте наличие файла в директории, добавьте побольше кода в вопрос касательно того как именно вы запрашиваете данный файл

Comment: добавил разрешение на чтение. Также перенес файл просто в память телефона и вроде все заработало) Спасибо за помощь)